# Добавить в конец атрибута

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добавить в конец атрибута
Например:

```
<img src="" alt="тест в начале">
```

а при клике чтоб было так

```
<img src="" alt="тест в начале строка конец">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На чистом JS:

```
document.getElementById('imgID').alt += ' строка конец';
```

На JQuery:

```
var old = $('#imgID').attr('alt');
$('#imgID').attr('alt', old + ' строка конец')
```